# please solve my solana wallet's hacking issues

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-py

My Solana wallet mnemonic was stolen. Hackers keep stealing tokens that are airdropped to my Solana wallet. This time, the wormhole token was airdropped on April 3, and when I looked at the wallet transaction, there was a transaction that the hacker had already worked on. (Link: https://solscan.io/tx/s2JdkWdx3VBFAjwmiN75mEVvESu9npRa5kwKPW6FT1NN5M9iP3bKnnq8Mau1WSLYRUeX4kMRMnB6PvSCf2EHxBV) The questions are as follows. Same.

1. It seems that the hacker did not transfer Solana to the wallet but paid the fee from another wallet. Is this possible?
2. I want to retrieve this wormhole token, but I need a Python code that can fight and win against hackers. Please help. It's not much, but I'll reward you with 10% of the tokens I saved from hackers! (Can I do this?)
3. It seems that the hacker did not transfer Solana to the wallet but paid the fee from another wallet. Is this possible?
4. I want to retrieve this wormhole token, but I need a Python code that can fight and win against hackers. Please help. It's not much, but I'll reward you with 10% of the tokens I saved from hackers! (Can I do this?)